# Trying to 'emulate' a document folder

Tags: windows, vb6, executable, virtualization

I am a 3rd party, and I would like to start an 1st party application and virtualize somehow a document folder that I would decide the location.
The first application would not touch the real 'my document' folder but instead save the file in a location I would set.
I don't want to change the registry entries for the personal folders, I want it just for this application.

I did some research but didn't find anything like that. Is that possible without a virtual machine? I would try to work in VB6, I want to test something on xp and win7. It's about a game redesign, and I would like the person to be able to have my program, and the original game installed on the PC without the configuration folders in 'my document' colliding.

I should mention that I cannot pass parameters to it because I am launching the 1st party application through a 2nd party executable already.

Thank you!
Yanick

Comment: I think there are 2 problems here. The first is VB6. The second is your question may be too broad. From the close reason excerpt: _There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Comment: Hi @C-Pound,
I don't absolutely need to use VB6.
The problem is simple and the solution could be anything that works, I haven't find anything that would and I prefer not virtualizing a whole computer just for this..., I want to have a modded version of a game, but I don't want all the settings and configurations (which are in my document) to merge with the one of the original game if the person has it installed.
The executable of the game automatically create its settings in 'My Document' by default.
Thank you for your time,
Yanick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to search the executable with a hex editor and manually edit it to another folder. Of course I had to choose a folder with less or equal number or character in the path.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, with a text file (or a program). MS made it easy.

Here is someone quoting my post, who is quoting Raymond Chen directly,

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/re-create-system-folder.522854/

**Creating Shell Extensions with Shell Instance Objects**
 Raymond Chen
 Microsoft Corporation

February 2000

Summary: A traditional shell namespace extension requires the implementation
 of a COM in-process server. Shell instance objects allow you to create
 simple shell extensions without having to write a single line of code. This
 article describes how shell instance objects and shell command objects can
 be used to easily deploy simple shell extensions. (5 printed pages)

Contents
 What Is a Shell Namespace Extension?
 What Is a Shell Instance Object?
 Shell Objects That Can Be Created as Shell Instance Objects
 How About an Example?
 Shell Command Objects
 Conclusion

What Is a Shell Namespace Extension?
 Shell namespace extensions allow you to create "virtual folders" in the
 shell. For example, the Recycle Bin icon on the desktop is not an actual
 file system directory, but rather represents a collection of items that is
 maintained by the Recycle Bin shell extension.

Details on creating shell namespace extensions can be found in the Platform
 SDK section of the MSDN Online Library
 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/psdk/shellcc/shell/shell_adv/namespace.ht
 m).

Writing a shell namespace extension can be quite an ordeal. Fortunately, the
 shell provides an easy way to create certain types of simple shell namespace
 extensions, as this article will show.

What Is a Shell Instance Object?
 A shell instance object is a special kind of shell extension provided by the
shdocvw.dll component. Whereas a traditional shell extension requires a DLL
 to implement the object, a shell instance object retrieves everything it
 needs to know from the registry.

How the shell creates a shell instance object

1.. The shdocvw.dll component is loaded by virtue of being registered as
 the InProcServer32 for the shell instance object.

2.. When shdocvw.dll is asked to create an object it does not otherwise
 recognize, it checks the registry key for a subkey named Instance. If found,
 it reads the CLSID value of that subkey and passes that CLSID to the
 CoCreateInstance function. (For lack of a better term, let's call this the
 "host" object.)

3.. Next, shdocvw.dll looks for a subkey of Instance named InitPropertyBag
 or InitStream. If found, it then creates an IPropertyBag or IStream
 (accordingly) based on the contents of the registry key and passes it to the
 IPersistPropertyBag::Load or IPersistStream::Load method (accordingly).

4.. Finally, shdocvw.dll returns the now-initialized host object as the
 shell instance object.
 Shell Objects That Can Be Created as Shell Instance Objects
 There are two shell objects that support being the host object of a shell
 instance object, namely the Shell link object and the Shell folder shortcut
 object.

Both of these objects support the IPersistPropertyBag interface, so you can
 use the InitPropertyBag method of initializing them. (It so happens that
 both objects also support IPersistStream, but initializing a shortcut from a
 registry stream is much more cumbersome.)

The property bag you provide in the registry describes the target of the
 shell link or shell folder shortcut object. There are three supported forms
 for this property bag.

Targeting a shell special folder

```
InitPropertyBag
 TargetSpecialFolder=REG_SZ:"<special folder number>"
```

Notice that this is a REG_SZ registry value even though it represents an
 integer. Both decimal and hex notation are supported.

Targeting a directory inside a shell special folder

```
InitPropertyBag
 TargetSpecialFolder=REG_SZ:"<special folder number>"
 Target=REG_SZ:"<subdirectory name>"
```

The subdirectory name can contain embedded backslashes.

Targeting a directory by explicit path

```
 InitPropertyBag
 Target=REG_SZ:"<full path to target directory>"
```

How About an Example?
 Here's a copy of the registration that creates the Fonts folder icon in
 Control Panel:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
 CLSID
 {D20EA4E1-3957-11D2-A40B-0C5020524152}=REG_SZ:"Fonts"
 InfoTip=REG_SZ:"Displays and manages fonts on your computer"
 DefaultIcon=REG_EXPAND_SZ:"%SystemRoot%\system32\main.cpl,9"
 InProcServer32=REG_EXPAND_SZ:"%SystemRoot%\system32\shdocvw.dll"
 ThreadingModel=REG_SZ:"Apartment"
 ShellFolder
 Attributes=REG_DWORD:0x60000000
 WantsFORPARSING=REG_SZ:""
 Instance
 CLSID=REG_SZ:"{0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}"
 InitPropertyBag
 TargetSpecialFolder=REG_SZ:"0x0024"
 Target=REG_SZ:"Fonts"
```

Because {D20EA4E1-3957-11D2-A40B-0C5020524152} is registered in the Control
 Panel namespace, a Fonts folder shortcut is installed in Control Panel.

Let's go through this registry key step by step.

a.. The GUID {D20EA4E1-3957-11D2-A40B-0C5020524152} was generated by
 running the uuidgen program found in the Platform SDK. Of course, when you
 create your own instance objects, you should run uuidgen and use your own
 GUID. The name of the icon as it appears in the namespace is also provided
 here.

b.. The optional InfoTip string is displayed when the user hovers over the
 icon.

c.. The DefaultIcon string provides the name and icon index for the icon
 to display for this item.

d.. The InProcServer32 key must be set to the shdocvw.dll file, and the
 threading model must be set to Apartment.

e.. The ShellFolder key sets the Attributes to a collection of SFGAO_
 values, which we wish to apply to the folder shortcut. The SFGAO_FOLDER flag
 must always be set. Because the target is a file system folder, the
 SFGAO_FILESYSTEM flag is also set in the Attributes, and the WantsFORPARSING
 value is set to an empty string. (If the target is not a file system folder,
 the WantsFORPARSING value should not be created.)

f.. The Instance key sets the CLSID value to the string representation of
 CLSID_FolderShortcut. This indicates that the object instance should create
 a folder shortcut.

g.. The InitPropertyBag key indicates that the folder shortcut will be
 initialized with the IPersistPropertyBag interface. The two values inside
 the property bag specify that the target is the subdirectory "Fonts" in the
 special folder 0x0024, which is CSIDL_WINDOWS.
 Shell Command Objects
 Another type of shell extension object is an icon that when double-clicked
 runs a command. This, too, can be created without having to write a COM
 server. For example, here is a command object that is used by the My Network
 Places folder:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
 CLSID
 {D4480A50-BA28-11d1-8E75-00C04FA31A86}=REG_SZ:"Add Network Place"
 InfoTip=REG_SZ:"Connects to shared folders, Web folders, and FTP
 sites."
 DefaultIcon=REG_EXPAND_SZ:"%SystemRoot%\System32\netplwiz.dll,-107"
 ShellFolder
 Attributes=REG_DWORD:0x00000000
 Shell
 Open
 Command=REG_EXPAND_SZ:"rundll32 ..."
```

Most of this registry key should look familiar, so I will only highlight the
 differences from shell instance objects:

a.. There is no `InProcServer32` key.

b.. The Attributes of the `ShellFolder` key should omit the `SFGAO_FOLDER`
 flag because this item is not a folder.

c.. Instead of an `Instance` key, we have a `Shell` key, which has the same
 structure as a progid key. The "Open" verb is the default action for
 double-clicking. You can also create other verbs, which will appear on the
 context menu. For example, the Internet Explorer icon creates a custom verb
 called "Open Home Page."
 Details on the structure of the Shell key can be found in the Platform SDK
 section of the MSDN Online Library under the topic heading "Extending
 Context Menus"
 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/psdk/shellcc/shell/shell_basics/context.h
 tm).

Conclusion
 Shell instance objects and shell command objects allow you to deploy simple
 shell extensions with a minimum amount of work. For example, you might
 create a command object in the Control Panel folder called "Troubleshoot,"
 which runs a troubleshoot program. Or you might create a shell instance
 object that hosts a folder shortcut to a collection of system administrative
 tools on a shared network server. Shell instance objects and shell command
 objects allow you to easily deploy these types of shell extensions.

Comment: This is really interesting but it doesn't apply to my question because I'm only trying to block access to the 'My Documents' folder from only one application.